# Match strings between delimiting characters

Tags: regex, notepad++, emeditor

There are strings appearing in a line with other text which are delimited by opening and closing quote, like the ones below. I am trying to find a regex that would match the word/phrase with the comma as internal delimiter (or the whole externally delimited content if there is no comma as in the case of a single word/phrase). For example for these phrases:

```
‘verdichten’
‘verdichten, verstopfen’
‘dunkel, finster, wolkig’
‘fort sein, verloren sein, verloren’
‘von den Nymph ergriffen, verzückt, verrückt’
‘der sich halten kann, halten kann’
```

The result I would like would be:

```
[[verdichten]]
[[verdichten]], [[verstopfen]]
[[dunkel]], [[finster]], [[wolkig]]
[[fort sein]], [[verloren sein]], [[verloren]]
[[von den Nymph ergriffen]], [[verzückt]], [[verrückt]]
[[der sich halten kann]], [[halten kann]]
```

It should work in Notepad++ or EmEditor.

I can match with `(‘)(.+?)(’)` but I cannot find a way to replace as described.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option could be making use of the `\G` anchor and 2 capturing groups:

```
(?:‘|\G(?!^))([^,\r\n’]+)(?=[^\r\n’]*’)(?:(,\h*)|’)
```

In parts

- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `‘` Match `‘`
  - `|` Or
  - `\G(?!^)` Assert position at the end of previous match, not at the start
- `)*` Close non capturing group
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `[^,\r\n’]+` Match 1+ times any char except `,` or newline
- `)` Close group
- `(?=[^\r\n’]*’)` Positive lookahead, assert what is on the right is `’`
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `(,\h*)|’` Either capture a comma and 0+ horizontal whitespace chars in **group 2**, or match `’`
- `)` Close non capturing group

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ipBwAC/1)

In the replacement use:

```
[[$1]]$2
```

Output

```
[[verdichten]]
[[verdichten]], [[verstopfen]]
[[dunkel]], [[finster]], [[wolkig]]
[[fort sein]], [[verloren sein]], [[verloren]]
[[von den Nymph ergriffen]], [[verzückt]], [[verrückt]]
[[der sich halten kann]], [[halten kann]]
```

Comment: Amazing analysis, the only issue is that it adds extra space after opening brackets.

Comment: @greektranslator I have updated the answer to remove the extra space after the opening brackets. See https://regex101.com/r/B7B2jU/1

Comment: Yes, great, sorry, but it stills removes the space after the comma.

Comment: @greektranslator Ah I see, I think this would be it then https://regex101.com/r/ipBwAC/1 If you want to replace it with the quotes you could use those in the replacement. https://regex101.com/r/C3jsYP/1

Answer (score 1):

With the help of @The fourth bird's answer, here's a the regex that will not include the space characters at the extremities of the matches:

`(?:‘|\s*(?!^))([^,\r\n’]+)(?=[^\r\n’]*’)(?:(,)|’)`

Replacing with 
`[[$1]]$2`

will give the trimmed tokens:

```
[[verdichten]],[[verstopfen]]
[[dunkel]],[[finster]],[[wolkig]]
[[fort sein]],[[verloren sein]],[[verloren]]
[[von den Nymph ergriffen]],[[verzückt]],[[verrückt]]
[[der sich halten kann]],[[halten kann]]
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/4WxXXx/1)

Edit:
For the `test context ‘verdichten’ test context` example you gave, you can use:

`(?:‘|\G\s*(?!^))([^,\r\n’]+)(?=[^\r\n’]*’)(?:(,)|’)`

Comment: Whoops, apart from when these occur in context, which is what I need really, I.e.:

`test context ‘verdichten’ test context`