# Match strings between specific tags and convert to wikilinks

Tags: regex, notepad++, pcre, emeditor

This question is similar to another one I asked here: [Match strings between delimiting characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58084119/match-strings-between-delimiting-characters/58084310?noredirect=1#comment102578913_58084310) but I could not modify in order to perform the new task. (Solution should work with EmEditor or Notepad++)

I need to match text between specific tags, I.e. `<b class="b2">I have a lot of text, more text, some more text, text</b>` and then

1. Convert **first character only** after opening tag to lowercase (with the exception of the pronoun "I")
2. Convert content between commas to wikilinks (and eliminate the tag).

I have tried running a number of regexes to get close to this with multiple steps, i.e.

```
(<b class="b2">)(.)
[[\L\2

</b>
]]

(\[\[)(\w+), (\w+)(\]\])
\1\2]], [[\3\4
```

Input text:

```
Any text <b class="b2">I make laugh</b>: Ar. and P. γέλωτα. Some more text <b class="b2">Delight</b>: P. and V. [[τέρπω]].
Any text <b class="b2">I amuse oneself, pass the time</b>: P. διάγειν.
Any text <b class="b2">It amuses oneself with, pass the time over, amuse</b>: Ar. and P.
```

Expected output:

```
Any text [[I make laugh]]: Ar. and P. γέλωτα. Some more text [[delight]]: P. and V. [[τέρπω]].
Any text [[I amuse oneself]], [[pass the time]]: P. διάγειν.
Any text [[it amuses oneself with]], [[pass the time over]], [[amuse]]: Ar. and P.
```

Comment: `(with the exception of the letter "I")` - actually, it is pronoun `I`. You already gave an example with `It` -> `it`

Comment: This is correct, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This a one-step solution:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?:<b class="b2">|\G(, (?=.*</b>)))(I )?([^,<]+)(?:</b>)?`
- Replace with: `$1[[$2\l$3]]`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- *UNCHECK `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?:                 # non capture group
    <b class="b2">  # literally
  |                 # OR
    \G              # restart from last match position
    (               # group 1, a comma and a space
      ,             # a comma and a space
    (?=.*</b>)      # positive look ahead, make sure we have a closing tag after
    )               # end group 1
)                   # end group
(I )?               # group 2, UPPER I and a space, optional
([^,<]+)            # group 3, 1 or more any character that is not comma or less than
(?:</b>)?           # optional end tag
```

**Replacement:**

```
$1          # content og group 1 (i.e. comma & space)
[[          # double openning square bracket
$2          # content of group 2, (i.e. "I ")
\l$3        # lowercase the first letter of group 3 (i.e. all character until comma or end tag)
]]          # double closing square bracket
```

**Result for given example:**

```
Any text [[I make laugh]]: Ar. and P. γέλωτα. Some more text [[delight]]: P. and V. [[τέρπω]].
Any text [[I amuse oneself]], [[pass the time]]: P. διάγειν.
Any text [[it amuses oneself with]], [[pass the time over]], [[amuse]]: Ar. and P.
[[be at ease]], v.: P. and V. ἡσυχάζειν, V. ἡσύχως ἔχειν.
```

**Screen capture:**

[image]

Comment: Perfect solution!

Comment: Whoops, seems to grab text beyond the tag, for example becomes this: `<b class="b2">Be at ease</b>, v.: P. and V. ἡσυχάζειν, V. ἡσύχως ἔχειν.` becomes `[[be at ease]], [[v.: p. and v. ἡσυχάζειν]], [[v. ἡσύχως ἔχειν.`

Comment: @greektranslator: Fixed, see my edit, just add `(?=.*</b>)` at the end of group 1: `(, (?=.*</b>))`

Comment: Thanks, another similar case.  This: `<b class="b2">unknown</b>, τινί <span class="bibl">Od.2.175</span>; <b class="b2">unheard of, forgotten</b>, Mimn <span class="bibl">5.7</span>` comes out as

`[[unknown]], [[τινί ]]<span class="bibl">Od.2.175</span>; [[unheard of]], [[forgotten]], [[mimn ]]<span class="bibl">5.7</span>`

So "τινί" and "mimn" should not be affected, but they are.

Comment: It' a little bit more complex, change `\G(, (?=.*</b>))` into `\G(, (?=(?:(?!<b ).)*</b>))`, it works for given example. If you have other test cases, update your question and add all of them. It's difficult to see them in comment. Be aware that regex will become unreadable, you could have look at a HTML parser.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion; another issue is that the regex affects capitals that are not the first letter after the opening tag. For example here: `<b class="b2">Testing with Capitals inline</b>` The "C" in Capitals should remain a capital.

Comment: @greektranslator: As I said it will be clearer if you modify your question and add all test cases with expected result. For your last question, just change `\L` into `\l` in the replacement part that becomes: `$1[[$2\l$3]]` (Note the small `\l` instead of capital `\L`)

Comment: Thanks, it was just a one-liner, I thought it would be easy to copy. This syntax works for Notepad++ but fails in EmEditor, I can see a \E flag there to stop applying capitals, not sure how to implement though: http://www.emeditor.org/en/howto_search_replacement_expression_syntax.html

Comment: @greektranslator: Use 1 more capture group, `(I )?([^,<]+)` becomes `(I )?([A-Z])([^,<]+)` and replace `$1[[$2\L$3\E$4]]`

Answer (score 0):

You should do it in several steps.

---

Replace

```
<b class="b2">([^<]*)</b>
```

with

```
[[\1]]
```

Transforms `<b>` tags to wikilinks.

---

Replace

```
(\[\[[^,\[\]]*?)(\s*),(\s*)
```

with

```
\1]], [[
```

Tokenize text to wikilinks. However, it may need to be run severa times, to replace all commas. See [**here**](https://regex101.com/r/FTi02g/3).

---

Replace

```
\[\[([A-Z])
```

with

```
[[\l\1
```

Make sure in NPPP to select "Match case".

This transforms all capital letters after `[[` to lower case.

---

Replace

```
\[\[i(\s)
```

with

```
[[I\1
```

transform to restore pronouns at the beginning in upper case.

Comment: The point is that there is also other text containing commas, etc which I do not want modified.

Comment: Thanks, it looks better, only that the 2nd step adds a space after `[[`, I.e. `[[ pass the time]]`

Comment: In the example you have the source text has no space after comma, I.e.

`[[scsdfs,asdasda]]`. Just tested in both EmEditor and Notepad++ same result, I copied text carefully.

Comment: Great, that is solved, although first letter after `[[` is not lowercased in some cases. For example with these 2 strings:

`<b class="b2">Delight</b>: P. and V. [[τέρπω|τέρπειν]].`
and
`<b class="b2">Amuse oneself, pass the time</b>: P. διάγειν, Ar. and P. διατρίβειν.`

It becomes:

`[[Delight]]: P. and V. [[τέρπω|τέρπειν]].`
and
`[[Amuse oneself]], [[pass the time]]: P. διάγειν, Ar. and P. διατρίβειν.`

Comment: And the change to lowercase should not be done at a later post-processing stage, as there is other text (not in the tag `<b class="b2"`) after [[ that should remain unchanged.

Comment: Thanks, but as mentioned in previous note, I only want lowercasing in strings contained in that tag as there are other strings which contain [[ that I do not want lowercased, that is why in my example code, lowercasing occurs in first step where the tag (and first letter) are replaced.

Comment: And what would be the difference between `[[` and `[[`? Where does `[[` exist, other than wikilinks?

Comment: Further up in the code there could be `Text=[[File:` for instance, as well as in other cases which I can not check all now, that is why lowercasing should be limited to 1st step replacing opening tag + first letter. Or it could be preexisting links which should not be altered.